# How to remove Client Script Resource in the lifecycle?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

In a base class, the pre-render adds a Javascript to the page. In my derived class, I want to replace the Javascript with one of my own resource script.

If the script is being added like this in the base class:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource(typeof(GeomappingEditor), "SomeSpace.Resources.Scripts.Geomapping.js");
```

Then can I do something like this:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);

    //HOW TO OVERWRITE JAVASCRIPT FILE HERE?
}
```

The reason why I thought this may be possible is because sometimes Javascript is added onto a page with a key like this:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("geomapping", this.ApiScript);
```

So I know I can add another script in the page with "geomapping" being the key and it will overwrite the previous script. But it does not seem there is a key like this for "RegisterClientScriptResource". Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the base class, add a virtual/overridable method to register the script, and in the base class, you override it that method and don't call the base implementation.  That would override it.

ALso,